# how to insert image in to database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
CREATE TABLE  IMGTABLE   
(
    NAME  char,
    PHOTO blob
)
```

This is Query for imagetable:

```
import java.sql.*;  
import java.io.*;

public class arralistclaaa
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into imgtable values(?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, "sonoo");

            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("E:\\actsandrulesMobile_biggerb.png");
            ps.setBinaryStream(2, fin, fin.available());
            int i = ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(i + " records affected");

            con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is Java class code for insert image in database When i run this code then com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'NAME' at row 1  this Error is coming i dont know where is Problem to insert image in data base please help me why this Error is coming.

Comment: Your `NAME` column does not include a length

Comment: `available` is not a really a suitable method to ascertain the length of a file as it's purpose is to provide the number of bytes that can be read from the stream without blocking...while in practice this isn't always the case, the value returned may not be the actual size of the file.  `available` also returns an `int` and your file may be longer then that.  Instead use `File#length`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree with your comment, but it is not actually the problem of the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's why it's not an answer ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Fair point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you use char instead of varchar(100) in NAME column. Change Name column type to varchar

Comment: send me Query for table structure coz var char is not taking in mysql

Comment: varchar is a single word and user varchar(length). length may be 100 or what ever

Comment: `CREATE TABLE  IMGTABLE
   (    NAME  varchar(100),
        PHOTO      blob
   ) `

Answer (score 1):

The issue at hand is that your value for `NAME` is too long. Your table definition has it as a single character (Or zero characters? I honestly don't know what you get with `char` and no size).

Also, `PreparedStatement` includes a `.setBlob()` method that takes an `InputStream` as the second argument.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBlob%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29

Comment: i am using mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Change ´char´ to ´varchar´ in your table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE  IMGTABLE   
   (    NAME  varchar,
        PHOTO      blob
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of Storing entire Image in DB, Just Store Image Path in the column (upload Image in Server) and retrieve it and form the Path and Display it in Browser.